# how to change encoding of a geopackage in QGIS 3

Tags: encoding, geopackage, qgis-3

For other formats you just go to Label >> Properties >> Source and there's a clickable button to select from a list of locales; but this box is grayed out for GPKG, is there a way to change the encoding of this kind of files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to change the character encoding of GeoPackages because it is mandatory to use UTF. See http://www.geopackage.org/spec120/index.html#_ogc_geopackage_encoding_standard:

> TEXT – A sequence of characters, stored using the database encoding
>   (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE)

Comment: trouble comes when you export a shp to gpkg without having set the correct locale, I'm converting everything into gpkg but i have to do an additional step of checking encodings, R's library sf is good in guessing but sometimes it fails